# how to add div section using button click and display it on the view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

```js
js file

  var i = 0;
      var original = document.getElementById('middle-section');
      document.getElementById('btn').onclick = duplicate();
      function duplicate() {
          var clone = original.cloneNode(true); // "deep" clone
          clone.id = "middle-section" + ++i;
          // or clone.id = ""; if the divs don't need an ID
          original.body.appendChild(clone);
      }
```

```css
css file

.middle-section-name{
      position: absolute;
      left: 500px;
      top: 850px;
      width: 200px;
      height: 40px;
      background-color: #aaaaaa;
      border: 2px hidden;
    }

    .middle-section-edit{
      position: absolute;
      left: 700px;
      top: 840px;
    }

  .middle-section-edit img{
    width: 20px;
    margin: 5px;

  }
```

```html
view

<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="header">
    <p>header</p>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="container">

  <div class="logo">
  <div class="logo-part">
      <p>logo</p>
  </div>
  <div class="logo-name">
      <P>logo name</P>
  </div>
    <div class="logo-edit">
      <%= image_tag 'edit-logo.png'%>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="top-main-section">
    <div class="top-main-section-area">
        <p>top main section</p>
    </div>
    <div class="top-main-section-edit">
      <%= image_tag 'settings-logo.png'%>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="top-banner-section">
    <div class="top-banner-section-area">
        <p>top banner section</p>
    </div>
    <div class="top-banner-section-edit">
      <%= image_tag 'settings-logo.png'%>
    </div>
  </div>


  <div class="middle-section" id="middle-section">
    <div class="middle-section-name">

    </div>

    <div class="middle-section-edit">
      <%= image_tag 'settings-logo.png'%>
    </div>

    <div class="middle-section-area">
        <p>carosel</p>


    </div>


  </div>


</div>

<input type="button"  value="click" id="btn" onclick="duplicate()"/>
</body>
```

I'm new to rails and I tried to add div section on click and show in view.I try with this code but still did not work and the error in console is `cannot read property clone node of null`. I tried with different ways to make it work but still I failed. Here is the HTML file, JS file and, CSS file below with an error of `cloneNode undefined`. CSS and HTML files are working but JQuery doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

jquery not support with middle rails tags. therefore cannot clone or append div sections. the standard way is using rails nested attributes concept[rails cocoon gem support to this task](https://hackhands.com/building-has_many-model-relationship-form-cocoon/)

Answer (score 0):

The way you have it setup now is you're executing your duplicate function instead of attaching it to the event handler so that it can execute it for you later when somebody clicks on the `btn` div.

So change this

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = duplicate();
```

Into

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = duplicate;
```

You also have the same event attached to your input, so I recommend removing one of them.

Your other issue is as the above answer pointed out you're appending your clone to an invalid element.

If you want to append it to `middle-section` then change it to:

```
original.appendChild(clone);
```

Or if you want to append it to the `body`, change it to:

```
document.body.appendChild(clone);
```

Comment: It's not work for me. still same problem here 'cannot read property cloneNode is undefined'

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
original.body.appendChild(clone);
```

To this:

```
original.appendChild(clone);
```

And also:

```
document.getElementById('btn').onclick = duplicate();
```

To this:

```
document.getElementById('btn').addEventListener('click', function() {
    duplicate();
});
```

Here's a [Codepen example](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/oGmoGW).

Comment: Check the codepen example I posted - it's working for me, does it work for you?

Comment: it prints 'carosel' three times in codepen example. but my console gives cannot read property EventListner null and same issue. I want to repeat this div section again with colors and image

Comment: I'm not seeing this issue in the latest Chrome or Firefox, what browser are you using to view the Codepen?

Comment: Google Chrome is up to date
Version 62.0.3202.62 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Comment: Hmm, I have no explanation then for why the Codepen works for me but fails for you. I've even tried it on both OSX and Windows 10 just in case it was OS specific, but I don't get the error at all when viewing my example. If anyone else is seeing the error they might be able to troubleshoot a bit more but it works fine for me :/

Comment: your code pen example clone the all divs and print carosel. it's ok but i want to print with colors area in css file